# Use sharedPref or static arrayList for storing data

Tags: android, arraylist

I am developing an app in which I require to share data between different activities. For example filling a Sign-Up Form. I'm using 5-6 Activities. So by which procedure should I share the data between the different Activities. (`SharedPreferences` or `static ArrayList`?)

Comment: Prefer SharedPrefences over  static data.your static data may lost if you app restarted by os

Comment: If i use use static array will it create any memory issue ? like app hang or app slow

Comment: it will not hang but memory of arraylist will be kept..if the arraylist will be large set of data then your app will slow

Comment: I have 30-40 paramestres value

Comment: also you can make your data class Parcelable and pass it with Intent

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on what you want to do.
The SharedPreferences can be persisted on the device, so if your user for some reason cannot complete all the flow, it can later restart from the point where it was (being able to recollect the state).

If you use a static array nothing prevents that what's in there gets lost.
Is that what you want?